# What is Authorized Redirect URI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crm, zoho, vercel

I'm currently using Zeit.co for my frontend hosting, Firebase database, Google Functions as the backend, and I want to integrate a 3rd party CRM called Zoho.

As part of the initial process to get the access code from Zoho, the mandatory parameters from Zoho include `client_id`, `grant_type`, `client_secret`, and `Authorized Redirect URI`. I was able to generate all parameters from Zoho directly, except `Authorized Redirect URI`. As far as I know, this URI is the endpoint that Zoho will redirect the web browser to with the authorization code after authorizing the client.

The setup process is similar to the example specified in this [link](http://www.slightlynerd.com/journal/1556096686605/generate-leads-with-calendly--firebase-and-zoho--a-story-of-webhooks), except I'm not using Calendly, for those who need a specific example. It essentially details how the CRM requires the aforementioned parameters and using the access token obtained, one sets up a Google Function endpoint.

Zeit's documentation [here](https://zeit.co/docs/api/#endpoints/oauth2/exchanging-code-for-an-access-token) indicates that the URI should be https://zeit.co/oauth/authorize. However, when I sent the request through Postman, the response came back as:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_redirect_uri"
}
```

How do I obtain `Authorized Redirect URI`? Is it from the frontend platform? Or is it something I can obtain from the other far end, which in this case is the CRM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From **[Zoho's documentation](https://www.zoho.com/writer/help/api/v1/oauth-step1.html):**

### Authorized redirect URI

> **It is the callback URL that should be given while registering your app with Zoho. This determines where the API server has to redirect the user after completing the authorization flow. The value of this parameter must exactly match with one of the redirect_uri values that is listed for your project in the Zoho's Developer Console.
>   Please note that the redirect_uri should be character perfect i.e., the HTTP or HTTPS, case, and trailing slash ('/') of the redirect URLs must all match.**

---

### Example

> **http://www.example.com/oauth2callback**

More info can be found **[here](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/using-oauth-2.html#alink3)**. Hope it helps!

Comment: Found a [video](https://docs.zoho.com/file/7hv84d970d2913b9748c5be37750ab38708f6) that also explains more about registering your app in Zoho and another [example](https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth/web-apps/access-token.html) that can come in handy.