# Integrating Blazor webassembly app with Zoho authentication

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, zoho

Im trying to get started with this integration. im till in the exploration/researching phase of this, but havent been able to find a whole lot of information from Zoho. https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth.html

Has anybody done something similar to this?

Questions:

- For Zoho, what is the Authority i need to provide? the default is "https://login.microsoftonline.com/".
- Under Zoho API Console, what kind of client should i be adding (intuitively it seems like it should be a Client-based app, but it is asking for a javascript domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the following stackoverflow link.  It is almost the same question and the responders there suggest a couple of links and video that fill in the information on what they mean by "Authorized redirect URI" and how to figure out the one to use.

[What is Authorized Redirect URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687783/what-is-authorized-redirect-uri)

The link above is discussing an interface with Zeit.co, which I'm not familiar with. I'm guessing it is the client domain that they want to set up Zoho to interact with.

It is not fully clear to me what is meant by the term "Javascript domain" in the Zoho documentation for account access with a Client based application.  I think they mean the domain url of the client and that it is likely, but not definitely, running javascript.  In some cases this will be the same as the "Authorized Redirect URI".  So you might try putting the same URI in both fields to see if that will work.  Your WASM/Blazor client may work just fine since the information exchange will likely be in http rather than javascript.

Comment: Thanks. But what is Zeit? I read somewhere on Zoho that they currently dont support Open ID. So it seems there is no way to integrate Zoho as a provider with WASM blazor authentication.

Comment: In addition, do you have any feedback on the Client-based under Zoho Console? This option forces me to provide a "javascript domain". Since im using WASM/Blazor there is no javascript domain to provide.